# Django Query: get frequency of related objects by name

Tags: django

I have a list of rating objects, where every rating is associated with a studyspace

I'm trying to write a Query to return a breakdown of the number of votes for each given StudySpace

e.g.

- Maths Room: 10
- Physics Room: 2
- Art Room: 9

I've tried and come up with the following:

```
studyspace_rating_breakdown = ratings.values('studyspace').annotate(num_votes=Count('studyspace')).order_by('-num_votes')[:3]
```

However this returns the id of the studyspace.

```
[{'studyspace': 8, 'num_votes': 421}, {'studyspace': 7, 'num_votes': 91}, {'studyspace': 2, 'num_votes': 2}]
```

Is there a way I can modify the query to return the studyspace name field instead of the ID?

I don't want to have to write a templatetag to look up the studyspace name from the ID within the template

The models themselves:

```
class StudySpace(models.Model):
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    space_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    ...


class Rating(models.Model):
    studyspace = models.ForeignKey(StudySpace, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=3)
    ...
```

Comment: If you have `ratings.values('studyspace', 'studyspace__space_name')...`, does it show anything?

Comment: It worked!!!!! (I wasn't aware you could do this) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try to put up the answer in comment section, you could easily do:

`ratings.values('studyspace', 'studyspace__space_name')`

to show the related fields. For more info, check django query api for [values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values).